# Best way to serve static folder that is not presented in frontend build

Tags: nginx, deployment, static-content

I have the following situation. Web content of my app is located in a standard directory `/var/www/my.domain.com/html/`. Also I have a folder `users_statics` somewhere inside this directory, where my app stores some essential files that were uploaded by users. Note, that these files are not incorporated in frontend build, and during usage only URLs to this files are needed.

However, my deploy pipeline script deletes all files inside the `/var/www/my.domain.com/html/` and inserts new frontend build, which by default doesn't contain `user_statics` directory. For example:

```
rm -rf /var/www/my.domain.com/html/*
cp -av build/. /var/www/my.domain.com/html/
```

So I am obliged to store `user_statics` directory in some other location and after every deployment `rsync` it to the web content folder:

```
  mkdir /var/www/my.domain.com/html/.../user_statics
  rsync -qah ./user-statics-bkp/* /var/www/my.domain.com/html/.../user_statics
```

I am not sure this is the most desirable way to deal with this folder, since by this time I want to add API to the backend app to interact with its contents. Thus, for example I can run into the incorrect API calls to this folder during deployment process.

I see the following options but none of them seems to me perfect:

1. Somehow rewrite CD pipeline to "ignore" this folder during the deployment.
2. Move this folder to the `/var/www/html/` folder and write additional directives to nginx config file.
3. Open subdomain for this folder and create server block for this subdomain. However, I am not sure if this one folder "deserves" to be separated to the new server block.

From your experience are there any better ways to correctly deal with it?

Answer (score 0):

Finally I placed this folder in this path `/var/www/html/path/to/user_statics` and added simple location directive to the `sites-available/my.domain.com` nginx config file:

```
location /path/to/user_statics {
     root /var/www/html/;
}
```

So after that nginx proxies `user_statics` requests to this place in server file system, separate from `/var/www/my.domain.com/html/`.
By this moment this solution works for me well.